# docker swarm unlock key is lost

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

Hi I've lost the docker swarm key. I know it can't be recovered. However Is there a way to delete existing swarm at least ?
Or would I be not able to use that machine with docker ever again ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/) there is a parameter called --force-new-cluster. This could help in your case since it says it force creates new cluster from current state. (Im not 100% sure about the key).

"Nuke it" is always an option. That means you stop the docker process

```
systemctl stop docker
```

and then you remove the contents of the /var/lib/docker/swarm (or docker_base_location/swarm). And then restart the dockerdaemon:

```
systemctl start docker
```

and then you should be able to simply create new swarm with docker swarm init command

Comment: Yes --force-new-cluster could help create a new cluster, However the new docker swarm shows errors in it while creating new service or accessing anything in it. Any idea what could be the issue ? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any more details on the error itself?

Comment: This helped me to at least not to recreate my virtual machine for docker swarm. swarm data is lost though but it wasn't required.